# Preventing relayout on hiding status bar (faking SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE)

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I'm working on app that has a list view and a detail view and I animate from the list view to the detail view. While doing this I'd like to hide the status bar at some stage (preferably while still showing the list view in the background). The problem is that hiding the status bar using

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

causes the list view (or the detail view) to relayout. This makes things look jerky and also can cause a lot of processing that makes the animation drop frames. There exists a solution to this:

`setSystemUiFlags(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE)` on the list view or

`setSystemUiFlags(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)` on the detail view

but these don't work at all below API 16 (I'm targeting API 14 and above) and work inconsistently between manufacturers even on API 16 and above.

Is there anyway for me to hide the status bar without causing a relayout or just stop layout from happening for a while?

Comment: Just a thought, no idea if it will work as desired: Have you tried setting `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` on the `ListView`, or perhaps it's parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN) and [FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR)? Your window will then always extend up underneath the status bar, and you'll need to watch the insets to make sure you're not underlapping it with content, but this way you shouldn't be laid out again when the status bar hides or shows.