# Add view with animation by windowmanager below statusbar

Tags: android, android-animation, android-windowmanager, android-statusbar

I use windowmanager to add view.

```
 WindowManager.LayoutParams mWindowParams;
    mWindowParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    mWindowParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT;
    mWindowParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    mWindowParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    mWindowParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH ;

    mWindowParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    mWindowParams.windowAnimations = R.style.updown;
    mWindowManager.addView(mView, mWindowParams);
```

My problem is when animate view , it show from top of statusbar but I want animate from bottom from statusbar like chat notification of instagram in app (status bar over my view when set animate from -y to y=0).

slide_down.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
<translate android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="5000"/>
<alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="5000"/>
```

[image]

Thankyou , And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308030/preventing-relayout-on-hiding-status-bar-faking-system-ui-flag-layout-stable

Answer (score 1):

params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;

```
    params.x = 0;   //x position

    params.y = 0;
```